# Splitting an jpeg image in blocks in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing

Can anyone tell me how can an JPEG image be divided in 8 x 8 blocks in C++.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already have the image in memory and are preparing to perform a DCT on it?

Comment: I'm still a little unclear. Do you mean you have the compressed data in memory? If so, you'd want to perform an *inverse* DCT to recover the spatial data. In this case, it's already divided into 8x8 blocks. If you have "raw" pixels in memory and want to do JPEG compression, then you'd break it up into 8x8 blocks, and do DCT on each of those blocks.

Comment: Well let put it clear I have simple JPEG image on the hard drive and I want to open it in my program and then divide it into blocks , for further application of DCT and quantization techniques.

Comment: @NiVeR: If it's already JPEG compressed, then it's already divided into 8x8 blocks. Is your intent to try to do further compressed on the compressed data? The obvious alternative would be to decompress the JPEG, then do your DCT/quantization. In the latter case, the minor detail that it started out with JPEG compression is nearly irrelevant.

Comment: @JerryCoffin You are right, the JPEG is already divided into 8 x 8 blocks, but now I need some example of how would I access a specific block(or further a single byte of the 64 in the block).

Comment: @NiVeR: It depends on how you've stored it when you loaded it. Is it in a single array? Double array?

Comment: I don't have experience of image processing, that's why I asked of simple example of opening, storing, and accecssing the byte values of the blocks.

Comment: @NiVeR: Without a library, there's no simple way to manipulate the content of a JPEG file. To give some idea, the JPEG standard is 186 pages long. That doesn't even cover the usual (JFIF) file format (though the JFIF spec is *much* shorter (only 9 pages). You can get both from [w3c](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/).

Comment: So your advice is to use the library suggested by @Tony The Lion ?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the die-hard approach. My heart goes out to you. Expect to learn a lot, but be forewarned that you will lose time, blood and pain doing so.

The [Compression FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/compression-faq/) has some details on how JPEG works. A good starting point is Part 2: Subject 75: Introduction to JPEG.

In a nutshell, for a typical JPEG file, you will have to reverse the encoding steps 6 to 4:

1. (6) extract the appropriate headers and image data from the JFIF container
2. (5) reverse the Huffman coding
3. (4) reverse the quantization

You should then be left with 8x8 blocks you could feed into an appropriate inverse DCT.

Wikipedia has some details on the [JFIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure) format as well as Huffman tables and [structure of the JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) data within the JFIF.

I'm assuming you're looking to play with JPEG to learn about it? Because access to the raw encoded blocks is almost certainly not necessary if you have some practical application.

EDIT after seeing comments: If you just want to get a part of a very large JPEG without reading/decompressing the whole file, you could use ImageMagick's `stream` command. It allows you to get a subimage without reading the whole file. Use like e.g. `stream -extract 8x8+16+16 large.jpeg block.rgb` to get a 8x8 block starting at (16,16).

Comment: I am interested in learning and developing Face Recognition software in future.But for now I want to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decompress the image, use the turbojpg library (it's very fast), which will give you an array of `unsigned char` as RGB (or RGBA).  Now you have an uncompressed image, which has a byte value for R G and B respectively.

You can from here, go and make a simple for loop that will go through 3*8 `char` blocks and copy them, using `memcpy` to some other memory location.

You have to keep in mind that the array returned from the turbojpg library is a **one dimensional** linear array of bytes.  So the scanlines are stored one after the other.  Take this into account when creating your blocks, cause depending on your needs, you'll have to traverse the array differently.

Comment: I want to do it without using any external library.

Comment: So you want to write the JPEG decompression functions yourself?  I wish you good luck my friend, and from experience, I can tell you it's not going to be easy, if you want any decent speed!

Comment: Well for first I want just to open the image and represent it in 8 x 8 pixel blocks, but the only way I can think of has complexity O(w * h) where w and h are the weight and height of the picture, and this is of course too slow.

Comment: How could you possibly read a w * h image in less than O(w * h) time?